# Visual Studio PowerShell Making Listbox DragDrop files Usable

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019

I have set a `listbox` up in my Windows Form where i can drag and drop files into it, the first thing i want to achieve is to show filename only not the Path, please see below my code block.

```
$handler = {
  $_.Data.GetFileDropList() | % {
    $listbox1.Items.Add($_)
  }
}
$listbox1.AllowDrop = $true
$listbox1.Add_DragEnter({$_.Effect = [Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]::Copy})
$listbox1.Add_DragDrop($handler)
```

the second objective is to be able to run my `PowerShell` combine `.pdf` script within the `listbox1`.

[image]

my `.pdf` combine script is below

```
$button2_Click = {

$pdftk = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe"
$inputFolder = "E:\SIGNEDNOTES"
$outputFolder = "E:\out\"

$IntactScan = Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count}

If ($IntactScan -gt $maxItems) {

   Get-Childitem $inputFolder -filter *.pdf -Recurse 
   pdftk "E:\SIGNEDNOTES\*.pdf" cat Output $outputFolder\Rename.pdf

   Move-Item "E:\SIGNEDNOTES\*.pdf" "E:\Backup\"
}
else {
    exit
}
}
```

basically i want the user to be able to drag 2 x pdf files into the `listBox1` and press the combine button and that outputs the combined `.pdf` to the second `listBox2`

Comment: If you want to retain the value of the underlying object (`C:\the\full\path\to\the\file`) but _only display_ `file`, you're better off creating customobjects, assigning your input collection to `$listbox1.DataSource` and then set [`$listbox1.DisplayMember = 'SomeCalculatedPropertyName'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you for your repluy would you have an example of what i could do to get this working please

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Having a `DataSource` i would have to list all the possible `.pdf` file names is that how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regards to my first question this is on going but the less important one out the 2

i solved the other one question (combine 2 pdfs from listBox) by code below

````
$pdftk = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe"
$inputFolder = $listbox1.Items
$outputFolder = "E:\out"

$CountyCount = Get-ChildItem $inputFolder -File | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count}

If ($CountyCount -gt $maxItems) {

   Get-Childitem $inputFolder -filter *.pdf -Recurse 
   pdftk $listbox1.Items cat Output $outputFolder\Combine.pdf

    $listbox1.Items.Clear()

    #Move-Item "E:\SIGNEDNOTES\*.pdf" "E:\Backup\"
}
else {
    exit
}

}```

thank you for your help
````

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the only way to show something *different* than the actual underlying item value is to use the `DataSource`/`DisplayMember` properties rather than adding file names directly to `Items`:

```
# Create datatable to hold the dragged files
$droppedFiles = [System.Data.DataTable]::new()
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('Name')
[void]$dt.Columns.Add('Value')

# ...
# Instruct the box to get the items from the datatable and use the `Name` column for displaying entries
$listbox1.DataSource = $droppedFiles
$listbox1.DisplayMember = 'Name'
```

And then, in your drop handler:

```
$handler = {
  $_.Data.GetFileDropList() | % {
    $name = (Get-Item $_).Name
    $droppedFiles.Add([pscustomobject]@{Name = $name; Value = $_})
  }
  $listbox1.Refresh()
}
```

You can still use `Items` for read-only access to the items provided by the data table

Comment: i have put you code into my script but it wont show any files when i drop into the box ```[ERROR] You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
[ERROR] At C:\Users\Sa\source\repos\TESTGUI\TESTGUI\Form12.ps1:9 char:1
[ERROR] + [void]$dt.Columns.Add('Name')
[ERROR] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ERROR]     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
[ERROR]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull```